# How to read formfield data using openxml in word document?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

How to read formfield data using openxml C# in word document?
I have textBox Inputs and dropdown lists in word document as formfields, I want to read values entered in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To receive a proper answer, you'll need to show what you have done so far, ideally as a [mcve]. 
Then tell us what exactly does not work (explicitly you may say e.g. "I am experiencing this but I am expecting that"). 
See our guide How to ask for more information.

Comment: I recommend you use the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to open a document of the type you want to read. There you can 1) see the underlying Word Open XML that makes up the document (the form fields) and 2) the code the Tool suggests in order to create the document. That will give you an idea of the structures involved and the object model of the SDK required to work with them. FWIW form fields are very complex structures, but reading the data from them is not too tedious.